# how to encrypt ckeditor image upload url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, ckeditor

after uploading image in ckeditor, it shows full image url.

how can i encrypt that url in ckeditor ?

that nobody can access or view the original image url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a javascript method on the CKEditor editor event and then encode the URL there. Like this.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['EDITOR_CK'].on('contentDom', function() {
    this.document.on('click', function(event){
        var uri = "test.aspx?id=abc";
        var res = encodeURI(uri);
        //then set this encoded url in the editor.
     });
});
```

Comment: but then i am sending email to someone ckeditor content, then how can i first decrypt to show image in url ?

Comment: Not understood your question, please elaborate

Comment: i am sending an email to user, whatever he/she insert html in ckeditor as email body.
but i do not want any user to see my full image url..